# why do VALORANT and the Riot Client have two desktop shortcuts each?

Tags: pc, epic-games-launcher, valorant

I started downloading *VALORANT* via the Epic Games store. The Riot Client was then automatically downloaded along with it. I'm fine with that, but then I saw that four desktop shortcuts had been made - two for *VALORANT*, and two for the Riot Client.

[image: Proof I'm not a cuckoo clock]

This is on pc (Windows 11), by the way.

Edit: I entered each shortcut, and as far as I can tell, all the duplicates do what they're supposed to.

The questions I have:

1. Is this common/has this happened to anyone else?
2. Which shortcuts should I use?
3. Would anything bad happen if I deleted one of each duplicate shortcut?

Comment: Is this a shared computer?

Comment: If they all point to the appropriate executables, then it should be fine to delete the duplicates. You can always create them again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Why this happen?

*Valorant* is just one game developed by *Riot Games*, whereas the ***Riot Client* is a client through which you can launch any game provided by them**, currently including: *League of Legends*, *Legends of Runeterra*, *Team Fight Tactics*, and *Valorant*.

When you install any *Riot game*, the *Riot Client* is automatically installed, it is designed to open, close, and update the games. It also simplifies the login process since all games are accessed through the same *Riot* account.

#### Answering your questions:

##### Is this common/has this happened to anyone else?

This is a bug that occurs in *Epic Games* due to the installation itself already creating shortcuts, but ***Epic* recreates them, resulting in 4 shortcuts instead of 2**. The correct setup should have one shortcut for the *Riot Client* (with the Riot symbol) and another for the game you installed (with the symbol of the respective game).

##### Which shortcuts should I use?

It depends on what you want to do. If you want to launch more than one *Riot* game or play a game while another is updating, you can open the *Riot Client*, if you only want to play *Valorant*, use its shortcut.

It's important to note that **even if you use a game shortcut directly, the *Riot Client* will always open** (if it's not already open).

##### Would anything bad happen if I deleted one of each duplicate shortcut?

No, deleting it doesn't affect anything.

Comment: Does every game downloaded through Epic Games always have a duplicate shortcut?

Comment: I'm not sure, maybe yes, but only with *Riot Games*. I tested it with *Valorant*, and it happened.